# meaning of texas poon tappa

Tags: meaning

I wonder the meaning of **texas poon tappa**.

I searched in Google and found this.

> the tappa is an individual that rolls into the great south and taps poons with reckless regard for safety.

But I don't understand the definition. Could anyone explain it easily?

Answer (score 1):

**poon** is a non-count noun; sexual slang (female sex organ).

**tappa** represents dialect pronunciation of the word **tapper**, he who taps (i.e. puts a bung in a barrel).

Comment: ... so it means someone (likely male) who has unprotected sex with women without regard to their own medical health.

Comment: Ifn you say so, ma'am.

Comment: A related word is [*poontang*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/poontang).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to burst your bubble but Texas poon tappa is a reference from *The Office* in the last season. (It was someone’s username on YouTube that Andy got pissed at) It’s not a real thing and someone posted the urban dictionary definition as a joke.